# Add class to random multiple spans

Tags: jquery, html, css, random, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a word cloud in which 3 words (randomly out of about 30 words) have to animate to another color (one color). This process should be repeated like every 2 seconds. I now have working code where only one span is animated to the color. Any ideas how I could get this working?

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/z6nv18ck/

```
setRandomClass();
  setInterval(function () {
    setRandomClass();
  }, 2000);

  function setRandomClass() {
      var wordcloudtext = $("#wordcloudtext");
      var items = wordcloudtext.find("span");
      var number = items.length;
      var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * number));
      items.removeClass("green");
      items.eq(random).addClass("green");
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just repeat the same thrice!

```
function setRandomClass() {
    var wordcloudtext = $("#wordcloudtext");
    var items = wordcloudtext.find("span");
    var number = items.length;
    var random1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * number));
    var random2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * number));
    var random3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * number));
    items.removeClass("green");
    items.eq(random1).addClass("green");
    items.eq(random2).addClass("green");
    items.eq(random3).addClass("green");
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/z6nv18ck/1/